# Show image on a comment node in Drupal site

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I visit a site made with Drupal, and when people comment they are not allowed to show the image they put in their comments. Only the link of the image is allowed.
But one guy can do that, he shows images in the comments!!! How is that possible, if the addministrators of the site put a filte that will discard out the  tag, how can he succeed?

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the site?

Comment: By image, do you mean those emotes?

Comment: no, a jpg image for example. It is not possible to view the image on the post, like this http://www.peshkupauje.com/comment/959916#comment-959916

Comment: Sorry, not enough details. Can't help